# I don't get why it won't execute the function

Tags: python, discord

So, I wanted to build a discord bot for my server. And now I try to add a ticket system with a reaction listener. It works to the point where I want to send a message in the newly created ticket channel. It just won't do it and it doesn't give me any errors. Here is the code:

NOTE: This is my first project and I'm a beginner :>

```
import asyncio


def ticketsys():
    from main import bot
    from hikari import GuildReactionAddEvent, Permissions, Embed
    from config import TICKET_MESSAGE, TICKET_CHANNEL, TICKET_CATEGORY, DEFAULT_GUILD, STAFF_ROLE_ID

    # This function reacts to the ReactionAdd class and deletes it right away.
    # It then creates a channel and stores it in the returned value for further use in the permission overwrites

    @bot.listen()
    async def ticket_handler(event: GuildReactionAddEvent) -> None:
        if event.message_id == TICKET_MESSAGE:
            await bot.rest.delete_reaction(message=TICKET_MESSAGE,
                                           channel=TICKET_CHANNEL,
                                           user=event.user_id,
                                           emoji="")

            ticketch = await bot.rest.create_guild_text_channel(name=f"{event.member.display_name}\'s Ticket",
                                                                category=TICKET_CATEGORY,
                                                                guild=DEFAULT_GUILD)

            queue1 = asyncio.Queue()
            ticket_channel = ticketch.id
            await queue1.put(ticket_channel)

            ticketch_CLIENTALLOW_perms = (Permissions.SEND_MESSAGES
                                          | Permissions.VIEW_CHANNEL)

            ticketch_STAFF_ALLOW_perms = (Permissions.MANAGE_MESSAGES
                                          | Permissions.VIEW_CHANNEL
                                          | Permissions.MANAGE_CHANNELS
                                          | Permissions.MENTION_ROLES)

            await bot.rest.edit_permission_overwrite(channel=await queue1.get(),
                                                     target=event.user_id,
                                                     target_type=1,
                                                     allow=ticketch_CLIENTALLOW_perms)

            await bot.rest.edit_permission_overwrite(channel=await queue1.get(),
                                                     target=STAFF_ROLE_ID,
                                                     target_type=0,
                                                     allow=ticketch_STAFF_ALLOW_perms)

            await bot.rest.edit_permission_overwrite(channel=await queue1.get(),
                                                     target=1136311522184921300,
                                                     target_type=0,
                                                     deny=Permissions.VIEW_CHANNEL)

            print(await bot.cache.get_guild_channel(channel=await queue1.get()))

        embed = Embed(title="Your ticket has been created.",
                      description="Please be patient as we try our best to get to your case. \n"
                                  "Be aware, that the staff also has to sleep and keep their life together."
                                  "If they haven't responded in at least three hours, feel free to ping them.",
                      color="#14f541")
        await bot.rest.create_message(channel=await queue1.get(),
                                      content=f"<@{event.user_id}> \n{embed}",
                                      user_mentions=True)
        await bot.rest.create_message(channel=await queue1.get(),
                                      content=f"<@{STAFF_ROLE_ID}>",
                                      role_mentions=False)

        await bot.rest.create_message(channel=await queue1.get(),
                                      content=f"Test",
                                      role_mentions=False)
```

I tried using the Queue feature from asyncio but that didn't work.
It would be nice if someone could tell me why it doesn't send the message in line 36

Comment: It looks like you're never calling the outer `ticketsys` function.  Either delete that `def` and unindent everything one level, or add a call to it at the bottom.

Comment: Any reason you chose Hikari over a more maintained, documented and developed library such as discord.py?

Comment: @RoadieRich The ticketsys function is called in the main file.

Comment: @SimonT Discord.py is being discontinued as far as I'm aware

Comment: [discord.py development resumed a while ago](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/c4324f17a80c94776832430007ad40e6)

Comment: @AJfortheSky Discord.py has been back and in active development for over a year.

Answer (score 0):

`Queue.get()` removes the returned item from the queue, so it only ever returns once in your code.  If the queue is empty, it will wait until an item is available, in your case, forever.

You probably shouldn't be using a `Queue` here in the first place.  Instead, pass your `ticket_channel` in a standard variable.

```
def ticketsys():
    from main import bot
    from hikari import GuildReactionAddEvent, Permissions, Embed
    from config import TICKET_MESSAGE, TICKET_CHANNEL, TICKET_CATEGORY, DEFAULT_GUILD, STAFF_ROLE_ID

    # This function reacts to the ReactionAdd class and deletes it right away.
    # It then creates a channel and stores it in the returned value for further use in the permission overwrites

    @bot.listen()
    async def ticket_handler(event: GuildReactionAddEvent) -> None:
        if event.message_id == TICKET_MESSAGE:
            await bot.rest.delete_reaction(message=TICKET_MESSAGE,
                                           channel=TICKET_CHANNEL,
                                           user=event.user_id,
                                           emoji="")

            ticketch = await bot.rest.create_guild_text_channel(name=f"{event.member.display_name}\'s Ticket",
                                                                category=TICKET_CATEGORY,
                                                                guild=DEFAULT_GUILD)

            ticket_channel = ticketch.id
            

            ticketch_CLIENTALLOW_perms = (Permissions.SEND_MESSAGES
                                          | Permissions.VIEW_CHANNEL)

            ticketch_STAFF_ALLOW_perms = (Permissions.MANAGE_MESSAGES
                                          | Permissions.VIEW_CHANNEL
                                          | Permissions.MANAGE_CHANNELS
                                          | Permissions.MENTION_ROLES)

            await bot.rest.edit_permission_overwrite(channel=ticket_channel,
                                                     target=event.user_id,
                                                     target_type=1,
                                                     allow=ticketch_CLIENTALLOW_perms)

            await bot.rest.edit_permission_overwrite(channel=ticket_channel,
                                                     target=STAFF_ROLE_ID,
                                                     target_type=0,
                                                     allow=ticketch_STAFF_ALLOW_perms)

            await bot.rest.edit_permission_overwrite(channel=ticket_channel,
                                                     target=1136311522184921300,
                                                     target_type=0,
                                                     deny=Permissions.VIEW_CHANNEL)

            print(await bot.cache.get_guild_channel(channel=ticket_channel))

        embed = Embed(title="Your ticket has been created.",
                      description="Please be patient as we try our best to get to your case. \n"
                                  "Be aware, that the staff also has to sleep and keep their life together."
                                  "If they haven't responded in at least three hours, feel free to ping them.",
                      color="#14f541")
        await bot.rest.create_message(channel=ticket_channel,
                                      content=f"<@{event.user_id}> \n{embed}",
                                      user_mentions=True)
        await bot.rest.create_message(channel=ticket_channel,
                                      content=f"<@{STAFF_ROLE_ID}>",
                                      role_mentions=False)

        await bot.rest.create_message(channel=ticket_channel,
                                      content=f"Test",
                                      role_mentions=False)
```